# Preventing web links from opening a native app, stay in web browser

Tags: android, web, hyperlink, deeplink

I have a website that also has corresponding a verified Android native app. My Andriod app is setup so that when users come to my site, they are asked to open in app. Is there a way to create a link on my webpage that will not automatically prompt user to "open in app" when users are on my website on their Android devices, and also already have the app installed?

I have tried to understand more in the API DOCs:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Idealy I would have somthing that looks like this :

```
<a href="mywebsite.com/webpage">Web page example<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I dont believe this is possible without making changes to the manifest in the app's code.